# "Program to an interface, not an implementation" paradigm in the context of scala traits and case classes

Tags: scala, traits, case-class

I'm currently stuck with the "program to an interface, not an implementation" paradigm in the context of scala traits and case classes. Consider the following scenario:

```
trait Foo {
  def bar: String
}

case class FooImpl(override val bar: String) extends Foo

object Hello {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val foo = new FooImpl("bar")
    doSomething(foo);
  }

  def doSomething(foo: Foo) = {
     // how to use case class goodies of FooImpl here?
  }
}
```

**Basically my question is: How to use case class goodies such as pattern matching, copy etc. in the example above?**

Of course I could just cast `Foo` to `FooImpl` but this makes the whole "program to an interface" approach useless. Do I miss the obvious here?

Answer (score -1):

```
def doSomething(foo: Foo) = foo match {
    case FooImpl(x) => // whatever
    case SomeOtherImplementor(x, y, z) => // whatever
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but this is not exactly what I was looking for. Actually I do not want any references to concrete implementations inside `doSomething`. All implementations of `Foo` should be interchangeable without any changes to `doSomething`.

Comment: Then put it in `Foo`?  And if that's not it, then you need to be more specific.